# Using multiple repositories in same session causing a loss of data

Tags: magento2

I have the following code that should create 2 simple products and a product relation. When adding a link via the link repository it seems to get rid of the stock from a product. This is not just limited to link repositories; adding a website via the website repository also has the same effect.

Code I'm using is similar to the below but correctly pushed through the constructor in my case.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to get around it / or can see if I'm doing anything wrong?

```
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
    $productRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface $productLink */
    $productLink = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository */
    $productLinkRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface');


    for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
        $product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface');
        $product->setSku('test_sku_' . $i);
        $product->setName('Test Product ' . $i);
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setPrice(5);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');

        /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem */
        $stockItem = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface');
        $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
        $stockItem->setQty(50);


        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory $productExtensionFactory */
        $productExtensionFactory = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory');
        $productExtension = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($productExtension === null) {
            $productExtension = $productExtensionFactory->create();
        }

        $productExtension->setStockItem($stockItem);
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($productExtension);

        $productRepository->save($product);
    }

    // If the code is exited here; the products are created with stock.


    // Related products one and two
    $productLink->setSku('test_sku_1');
    $productLink->setLinkedProductSku('test_sku_2');
    $productLink->setLinkType('related');
    $productLink->setLinkedProductType('simple');
    $productLink->setPosition(1);
    $productLinkRepository->save($productLink);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with Magento 2.0 versions. Since 2.1 it is now performing as expected and the above code creates the products; linked and with stock as expected.